# What do we mean by Tracking In styling ? How we can implement Tracking w.r.t styling using xsl?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

In few of the competitive xslt technical sessions I saw they use to mention a styling chart where they are mentioning while writing xslt make sure we are using the specification like

```
Tracking: -3
Kerning: Optical
```

Now I saw we have font-kerning: but that is limited to

```
font-kerning:auto|normal|none
```

I don't see a option like **optical** and also not getting any fruitful information about tracking; so if any one can help me with the input  **how I can implement this Tracking and Kerning options in my .xslt** that will be helpful.

Comment: Optical kerning uses the outlines of the characters and tries to regularise the amount of white-space between adjacent characters. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning#Automatic_and_manual_kerning) I don't know of any XSL-FO formatter that implements optical kerning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tracking** is just a different term for letter spacing:

> In typography, **letter spacing**, **character spacing** or **tracking** is an optically consistent adjustment to the space between letters to change the visual density of a line or block of text.
> <sub>source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_spacing)</sub>

In XSL-FO the corresponding property is [`letter-spacing`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#letter-spacing).

There is no FO property controlling **kerning** (`font-kerning` is a *CSS* property), but if the font you choose has kerning information *and* the formatter you use supports it the resulting output will show the characters properly spaced.
If you are using FOP, kerning can be enabled / disabled when you [register the fonts](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/fonts.html#register); by default, it is enabled.

Comment: @Ifurini  Sorry may be i am asking much; but one more specification they do talk about line spacing (leading) ; which property should I use for that? (In case if we want a new question I can open one)

Comment: Line spacing is indirectly controlled with [`line-height`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#line-height) and [`line-stacking-strategy`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#line-stacking-strategy).